# Open three.js json file in blender

Tags: json, import, blender

I have a json [file](https://github.com/multiwii/baseflight-configurator/blob/master/resources/models/quad_atail.json). I guess it exported with [Three js exporter addon](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender). I don't have source of this file, but i want to open it in blender again and convert to another format. Is this possible ?

I installed a lot of exporters([this one](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Blender+Exporter) for example), but didn't find import from `JSON`. [Three.js exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) after install says:

[image]

Comment: Try the threejs fork [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39962639/2684771)

Comment: @sambler i can't install it. Choose option-> User preferences -> install from file and choose: `import_threejs.py`. But import option not shown.

Comment: It is a multifile addon, the three files listed on the github page make up the addon, place the three files into a folder and either zip the folder and then use the install from file and choose the zip or move the folder into blender's addons folder. It appears to read your file, the materials are there but not assigned to parts of the model.