# Blender import three.js json model with UV map

Tags: json, import, three.js, blender, uv-mapping

I guess not much people need to import three.js json file to Blender, but I lost my original Blender file and want to recreate it from json that I exported earlier.

Latest three.js git only has exporter and no importer.

I tried using old json importer (from this link https://github.com/Bangybug/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender/2.71/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs) but it does not load back UV maps, only model and textures, so I wonder if there is some importer that could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there currently is no working importer to get three.js models into blender. You could try to load the object in three.js and then export it using the THREE.OBJExporter(). You might have a good chance to import that resulting obj-file into blender.

Comment: can i load my json model with textures and uv maps to some online three.js editor? and then export from there?

Comment: you could try clara.io, that could probably work although I don't know for sure.

Comment: I tried clara.io but although it lets me upload texture images I dont see them wrapped around my model.

Comment: I wrote little sample that loads my model ok, and I called OBJExporter on it, but I dont get materials in obj file, just vertices, normals, tangents.

Comment: i believe the material-settings are not part of an .obj-file and the additional .mtl-file isn't generated. But it's probably the best you can get right now.